# ngModel not binding in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am creating directive to generalize control the data input from javascript.

so I have the options for text field specified as:

```
$scope.textfield = { name:"abcd", label: "abcd", placeholder: "xyz", required: true };
```

and directive as:

```
<text-input details="textfield" ng-model="abc.variable"></text-input>
```

the directive code looks as below:

```
csapp.directive("textInput", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            details: '=',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input-display label="{{details.label}}" class="{{details.class}}" required="{{details.required}}">' +
                        '<input type="text" name={{details.name}} placeholder="{{details.placeholder}}" ng-required="{{details.required}}" data-ng-model="ngModel"/>' +
                    '</input-display>'

    };
});
```

where as the parent directive code is as below:

```
csapp.directive("inputDisplay", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            class: '@',
            required: '@'
        },
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="control-group" class="{{class}}">' +
                        '<div class="control-label">{{label || "Text"}} {{ required.toString() === "true" ? "*" : ""}}' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="controls" ng-transclude>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
    };
});
```

if i use a single directive and merge the templates of the two directive the binding works but if i use separate directives for layout and input then it does not work.

I had tried with the dot operator ngModel but its still not working.

Comment: could  you set up a plunker with relevant code

Comment: It is because you are creating a scope in a scope in scope.  That is to say controller>textInput directive>inputDisplay directive.  Which brings me to my next point, Leonardo DiCaprio might start invading your dreams, so just be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ngModel Controller.

See the demo here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TULG36?p=preview

```
myApp.directive("textInput", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            details: '='                
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input-display label="{{details.label}}" class="{{details.class}}" required="{{details.required}}">' +
            '<input type="text" name={{details.name}} placeholder="{{details.placeholder}}" ng-required="{{details.required}}"/>' +
            '</input-display>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
            var input = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('input'));
            input.bind("input", function(e) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                   ngModel.$setViewValue(e.target.value);
                });
            });

            scope.$watch(function(){
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, function(modelValue){
                input.val(modelValue);
            });
        }

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'<input-display label="{{details.label}}" class="{{details.class}}" required="{{details.required}}">' +
                    '<input type="text" name={{details.name}} placeholder="{{details.placeholder}}" ng-required="{{details.required}}" data-ng-model="ngModel"/>' +
                '</input-display>'
```

Input-display transclude your input and you should use it as controller of the input is directive input-display controller.

Comment: can you please elaborate with example, not able to understand your point :(. btw, thanks for the reply.

Comment: just add details=details in template of the textInput directive and details: '=' in scope of the inputDisplay

Comment: inputDisplay directive has no details variable, and you should provide  it because transclude use $scope of directive where it's compiled